# Simple MPI_Gather test with memcpy error

Tags: c++, c, amazon-web-services, parallel-processing, mpi

I am learning MPI, and trying to create examples of some of the functions.  I've gotten several to work, but I am having issues with MPI_Gather.  I had a much more complex fitting test, but I trimmed it down to the most simple code.  I am still, however, getting the following error:

```
root@master:/home/sgeadmin# mpirun ./expfitTest5
Assertion failed in file src/mpid/ch3/src/ch3u_request.c at line 584: FALSE
memcpy argument memory ranges overlap, dst_=0x1187e30 src_=0x1187e40 len_=400

internal ABORT - process 0
```

I am running one master instance and two node instances through AWS EC2.  I have all the appropriate libraries installed, as I've gotten other MPI examples to work.  My program is:

```
int main()
{
    int world_size, world_rank;
    int nFits = 100;
    double arrCount[100];
    double *rBuf = NULL;

    MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    assert(world_size!=1);
    int nElements = nFits/(world_size-1);

    if(world_rank>0){
    for(int k = 0; k < nElements; k++)
    {
            arrCount[k] = k;
    }}

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(world_rank==0)
    {
            rBuf = (double*) malloc( nFits*sizeof(double));
    }

    MPI_Gather(arrCount, nElements, MPI_DOUBLE, rBuf, nElements, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(world_rank==0){
    for(int i = 0; i < nFits; i++)
    {
            cout<<rBuf[i]<<"\n";
    }}

    MPI_Finalize();

  exit(0);
}
```

Is there something I am not understanding in malloc or MPI_Gather?  I've compared my code to other samples, and can't find any differences.

Comment: You tagged this as C++, but this is not valid C++: `int nFits = 100;
    double arrCount[nFits];`.  Second, you never checked if `world_size==1` before doing this:   `int nElements = nFits/(world_size-1);`.  Third, what if `rBuf` is a null pointer when calling `MPI_Gather`?

Comment: `int nElements = nFits/(world_size-1);` should rather be `int nElements = nFits/world_size;` shouldn't it?

Comment: world_size = 3, one master and two nodes.  Elements are only split over the two nodes, but the world_size includes the master, so we are removing that from our number of elements.  rBuf should be Null in MPI_Gather for the processes that are not receiving, so world_rank == 1 and world_rank == 2 in this case.  So all the code works fine as-is.  None of those issues really address the error I am receiving.

Comment: @HoosierPhysics -- Yes, but you're not testing for any of these error conditions, and all we have is the code you posted.  We can't see what's behind those variables.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand.  For your first point, I changed the declaration to 100, for purposes of this test program.  For the second point, I asserted world_size != 1.  For the third point, the rBuf should be Null for the processes where world_rank > 0, the sending processes, and it should allocate memory for rBuf for world_rank == 0, the receiving process.  The program still ends up with an identical error.

Comment: You still have rank #0 sending data to itself, so the receiving buffer `rbuf` needs to be `nElements*world_size` long. At the moment, you have a buffer overflow. You can also consider using `MPI_Gatherv()` instead of `MPI_Gather()` if deemed more convenient.

Comment: @Gilles I still don't really understand.  rBuf is nElements*world_size long, since its current allocation is nFits * sizeof(double), and nFits = nElements*world_size.  Where is my buffer overflow coming from?

Comment: No `nFits` isn't equal to `nElements*world_size` because you have `nElements = nFits/(world_size-1)` (just read your code). But in any case, if you want to use `MPI_Gather()`, you need to make sure that your receiving buffer is at least `world_size*nElements` long, because that's what the library will use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `root` process in a gather operation does participate in the operation. I.e. it sends data to it's own receive buffer. That also means you must allocate memory for it's part in the receive buffer.

Now you could use `MPI_Gatherv` and specify a `recvcounts[0]`/`sendcount` at root of 0 to follow your example closely. But usually you would prefer to write an MPI application in a way that the root participates equally in the operation, i.e. `int nElements = nFits/world_size`.

Comment: Ah, this is exactly what I was confused about.  The examples and documentation on MPI_Gather didn't really make that clear.  This clears it all up for me.  If that's the case though, whats the best practice for implementing a master/node system with MPI?  If I have a system of a master instance and 100 node instances, and I am splitting up a calculation between them, do I really include the master in that process?  So split the calculation between 101 instances, and gather afterwards?

Comment: You might be mixing up the concepts of a **root** of a collective and a **master** in a master/slave system. A root is basically a normal process/rank which plays a special role in a collective operation. The root process usually participates in the calculation. Whereas a master is considered someone who is actively distributing tasks to the workers/slaves. The master process often does not participate in the computation. The master/slave idiom is used to dynamically assign tasks, whereas the collective operations usually operate on a domain decomposition.